# How do you remove Mobile Broadband Networks from the Gnome menu bar?

Tags: networkmanager, gnome-shell, modem, 3g, lte

I currently have a gnome menu that looks like this:

[image: My Gnome menu]

Can anyone tell me how I can remove the 3/4G mobile networks? I have an inbuilt mobile network device, which I've never used and would rather not see and recently the other 2 devices have appeared.They may have been plugged in to my laptop at some point.

I've checked and they don't appear in `/etc/NetworkManager`, and I don't see any config or extension that can help me remove them. They do appear in the NetworkManager applet, but the remove button is greyed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging around and some questions in IRC someone pointed out that these connections come from paired bluetooth devices.

Simply running:

```
bluetoothctl
```

Brings up a list of all paired bluetooth devices, running:

```
remove MACADDRESS
```

Removes the device described by MACADDRESS (simply copied from the results in bluetoothctl).